# How to prevent SQL Injection in Hibernate via POJO

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, tomcat

We are using Hibernate on Tomcat. We recently found a SQL injection vulnerability in our Hibernate code. Specifically in reguards to the POJOs we use for ORM.

We are taking in the user input and creating a new POJO like this:

```
//POJO associated with Foo.hib.xml
public class Foo{
    private String a;
    private String b;

    public Foo(String a, String b){
        this.a=a;
        this.b=b;
    }

    //Getters go here
}
```

We have many many pojos like this that are used in various rest services across various parts of our tomcat platmform. The problem we found is that users can set a sql query as a value for Foo so when we create it and save it, they can do sql injection:

```
//example of possible injection
Foo foo = new Foo("select * from *;", "insert * into * as *");
//save new Foo to hibernate
session.saveOrUpdate(foo); //above queries will be executed on insert
```

The above is just a generic example of what we are seeing.

I have looked all over and so far all I have found is examples for sanitizing data on queries and not on insert values through hibernate. Is there a way through hibernate to have it sanitize the data of a pojo before inserting it into the db?

Comment: hibernate doesn't actually execute that SQL though, does it?

Comment: I want to second that: unless there's some strange mapping option (which I've never heard of) it should be impossible to have Hibernate _execute_ the contents of a field as SQL! How do you come to this conclusion?

Answer (score 1):

**Simple Answer:**

You need to esnure that you are NOT concatenating the `HQL/SQL` query strings with input data directly like below:

```
//Unsafe Hibernate query, Never do this
Query query = session.createQuery(" from Employee where empId='"+inputEmpId+"'");
```

Rather, you need to set the data using `setParameter()` methods provided by `org.hibernate Query` API (or for JDBC `PraparedStatements` use `setString("")`, etc..) like below:

```
//Safe Hibernate query
Query query = session.createQuery(" from Employee where empId=:empId");
query.setParameter("empId", inputEmpId);
```

For **long answer**, you can look at [here](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).